# twitter application can not be revoked

Tags: twitter

I have a problem on my twitter account. More recently, I allow many applications to access my account. As a result, a lot of spam out without recognize me.

When I want to revoke access the application by clicking on the page Revoke Application `https://twitter.com/settings/applications`

Not a single work. I've repeated several times, but the button does not work.

Is there any other solution to solve this problem, for example by `twitter.com?revoke=ID_APP` or the other. I really need quickly to resolve this issue. Thank you

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You'd be better off asking Twitter support.

Comment: Yes go on https://twittercommunity.com.